# Finding $\mathbb{E}[X]$, $X \sim \text{Pareto}$ under exam conditions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking back at a past qualifying exam.

> Let $X$ be a Pareto distributed random variable with the density $$f(x
>  \mid \alpha, \beta) = \beta\alpha^{\beta}x^{-(\beta+1)}I(x > \alpha)$$
>   where $\alpha, \beta > 0$ are parameters.
>
> Let $Y = \log(X)$. Find the mean and variance of $Y$.

Explaining *how* to do this question is quite simple: we have
$$f_{Y}(y) = \beta\alpha^{\beta}(e^{y})^{-\beta+1}e^{y}I(y>\ln(\alpha))=\beta\alpha^{\beta}e^{-\beta y}I(y>\ln(\alpha))\text{.}$$
Hence 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \beta\alpha^{\beta}\int_{\ln(\alpha)}^{\infty}ye^{-\beta y}\text{ d}y$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\ln(\alpha)}^{\infty}ye^{-\beta y}\text{ d}y &= \left.y\left(\dfrac{-1}{\beta}\right)e^{-\beta y}\right|_{\ln(\alpha)}^{\infty}-\int_{\ln(\alpha)}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{-1}{\beta}\right)e^{-\beta y}\text{ d}y \\
&= \dfrac{\ln(\alpha)}{\beta}\alpha^{-\beta}+e^{-\beta\ln(\alpha)} \\
&= \dfrac{\ln(\alpha)}{\beta}\alpha^{-\beta}+\alpha^{-\beta} \\
&= \alpha^{-\beta}\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(\alpha)}{\beta}\right)
\end{align}$$
where I used the shortcut $$\int_{x}^{\infty}\beta e^{-\beta y}\text{ d}y = e^{\beta x}$$
for $x > 0$, due to this being the survival function of an exponential distribution,
and then 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \beta^{-1}+\ln(\alpha)\text{.}$$
However, $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ seems to be much more difficult to find - we have two iterations of integration by parts, and then we still have to square $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ - which unfortunately is an additive term, so then we have to expand that, take $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Y])^2$, etc.

This seems to be too long of an approach for this problem for a timed exam. Are there any "probabilistic" (density function, expected values of well-known continuous distributions, etc.) shortcuts for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $Z:= \ln(X) - \ln(\alpha) \sim \text{Exp(rate}=\beta$).
$$
f_Z(z) = f_X(\alpha e^z) \left\vert \frac{dx}{dz} \right\vert
= \beta \alpha^\beta (\alpha e^z)^{-(\beta+1)} \cdot |\alpha e^z| \cdot \mathbb{1}_{ \alpha e^z> \alpha}
= \beta e^{- \beta z} \cdot \mathbb{1}_{ z > 0}
$$
and from there calculating mean/variance of $\ln(X)$ is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $Y-\ln\alpha\sim\text{Exponential}(\beta)$